# How to put data from database table to a html table using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do is put my database table data to html table in my index page using ajax and php.

My problem is the data is not showing. Does anyone know whats the problem with my code?

html:

```
<table id="myTable2">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
url: 'process.php',
type: 'post',
data: {tag: 'getData'},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
        if(data.success){
            $.each(data, function(index, record){
                if($.is_numeric(index)){
                    var row = $("<tr />");
                    $("<td />").text(record.name).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(record.age).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(record.gender).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(record.action).appendTo(row);
                    row.appendTo('myTable2');
                }
            })
            }
        }
    });
$('#myTable2').dataTable({
        "bjQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
});
</script>
```

process.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if(isset($_POST['tag'])){
try{

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT name, age, gender, action FROM viewtables";
$result = $dbc->prepare($sql);

if(!$result->execute()) return false;
if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    $json = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch()){
        $json[] = array(
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'age' => $row['age'],
            'gender' => $row['gender'],
            'action' => $row['action']
        );
    }
    $json['success'] = true;
    echo json_encode($json);
}
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " .$e->getMessage();
}
}   
?>
```

Comment: if you are using `dataTables` plugin .. why not use it to render your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, this:

```
    row.appendTo('myTable2');
```

needs to be:

```
    row.appendTo('#myTable2');
```

since you're looking for `id=myTable2`, not a `<myTable2>` tag.

Though, as noted in Theodore's comment, you really want:

```
$('#myTable2 tbody').append(row);
```

Comment: I believe in this case its `$('#myTable2').find('tbody').append(row)`

Comment: +1 becuase I didn't know you could use selectors for children like that!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Paul, your selector is wrong

- hash is for id `$('#myTable')`
- period ( . ) is for class `$('.redTable')`
- no prefix for element (a, li, table) `$('table')`
- More advanced with attribute selectors `$(['href="importantLink.html"'])`

Check and make sure PHP is returing a good object for your script.
Make sure that your finding your DOM elements with the right selectors.

`$('#myTable2').find('tbody').append(row);` is what you are looking for