# Put data from Postgresql database to table using Ajax and PhP

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

The goal of my task is to populate data from postgresql database every 5 seconds using ajax and php. I followed the example [How to put data from database table to a html table using ajax and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047156/how-to-put-data-from-database-table-to-a-html-table-using-ajax-and-php/52296521?noredirect=1#comment91540919_52296521). I am new in PhP so, I don't know why data is not populating. I did testing of the code and got data in console successfully but not in table. 
**Client side code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> <?php include './../css/hardwarestatus.css'; ?> </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="maindiv">
        <div id="tagsDiv"> 
                <h3>Estat Tags</h3>
                <?php  

                        echo '<table id="tags_table">';
                        echo "<tr>";
                                echo '<th>' . "TAG" . '</th>';
                                echo '<th>' . "BATTERY" . '</th>';
                                echo '<th>' . " Time " . '</th>';
                                echo '<th>' . "Status" . '</th>';
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo '</table>';                            
                ?>
        </div>

</div>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        UpdateHTMLTable();
        setInterval(function() {
                UpdateHTMLTable();
        }, 5000); // 5000 millisecond(5 second)

function UpdateHTMLTable(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {


            myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);


            for (i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {

                console.log(myObj[i]);

                var row = $("<tr />");
                    $("<td />").text(myObj[i].mac).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(myObj[i].battery).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(myObj[i].ts).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(myObj[i].ts).appendTo(row);
                    row.appendTo('#tags_table');     
                } 
        }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "pages/estat_hardware_server.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**On server side, my code is**

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");  
        $host = ip of the host";
        $port ="port no."; 
        $user = "user"; 
        $pass = "123"; 
        $db = "db_name"; 
        $con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
        or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 
        $query = "Query string"; 
        $result = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");
        if(pg_num_rows($result))
        {
            $data=array();
            while($row=pg_fetch_array($result))
            { 
                $data[] = array(
                'mac'=>$row['mac'],
                'ts' =>$row['ts'],
                'battery'=>$row['battery']
                 );
            }         
            echo  json_encode($data);
            pg_free_result($result);
            pg_close($con);
        }                                
?>
```

Comment: There's is quite a lot that _could_ go wrong, so we'd need more information of how far you get, if there are any error messages, etc. - You'd need to do some more debugging first.

Comment: if you manually open `pages/estat_hardware_server.php` in a browser, are you getting the expected datas ?

Comment: Yes, I am getting all the data from server in client. as i did this on client side: console.log(myObj[i]); and the result is coming from server successfully.

Comment: `#mytags_table` is actually called `tags_table`, so this line `row.appendTo('#mytags_table');` should be `row.appendTo('#tags_table');`

Comment: first you should open : pages/estat_hardware_server.php and check if you see error there and share it with us. If no error there you should check browsers console

Comment: You have invalid HTML. `echo '<th>' . "TAG" . '</td>';` you're opening th tag and close a td one

Comment: @NoOorZ24 check the second comment.

Comment: what @cid said, and no `<tr>` for the header row.

Comment: Acknowledged, Updating....

Comment: After fixing issues you mentioned, Now, I am successfully getting data in table. One of the main issue was fixed by the comment :" #mytags_table is actually called tags_table, so this line row.appendTo('#mytags_table'); should be row.appendTo('#tags_table'); "

Comment: @Jeff This code working fine now, but the issue is that it keeps appending new data instead of replacing the old data.

Comment: the reason might be that you _do append_: `row.appendTo('#tags_table')`

Comment: You have to clear the table before appending (beware, the headers of the table will disapear too)

Comment: Is there any other solution? I don't want to clear all the data, as I will keep displaying some tags data as such without any modification. For.example if a certain hardware not working then I want to display the time from which It stop working, so it means that clearing all the data is not a good solution. I have to some more logics to do...I want to get the data already in the table, do some comparisons with the new data, and replace some of the data as per defined rules. I hope I make you clear what I want.

Comment: In my opinion, you should return the `id` of each line from PHP to your js. This way you can identify each line with the refreshing of data. You could set [jquery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) on each line and check if it change. I'll suggest you something

Comment: @Mcsky Acknowledged, I will try this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't tested this one but the approach is :

1. Generate the table from the php with id on each `td element` representing the identifier in database
2. On line set `data` attribute to identify which line has changed
3. When you get update data from your webservice you compare it to your jquery data elements

Something like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const tableEl = $('#tags_table');
    UpdateHTMLTable();
    setInterval(function() {
        UpdateHTMLTable();
    }, 5000); // 5000 millisecond(5 second)

    // An object returned by php reprensenting your data
    const rowHasChanged = function(obj) {
        const lineObj = $('tr#' + obj.id);
        if !(lineObj) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do your logic here
        if (lineObj.data('status') !== obj.status) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    function UpdateHTMLTable(){
        const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {   
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    const myObj = data[i];
                    if(rowHasChanged(myObj)) {
                        // Do your stuff to colorize the line, or something to alert
                    }
                }    
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "pages/estat_hardware_server.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
});
```

Don't forget to add all the related data and identifier to be able to compare with your webservice update

```
echo '<table id="tags_table">';
    echo "<tr>";
        echo '<th>' . "TAG" . '</th>';
        echo '<th>' . "BATTERY" . '</th>';
        echo '<th>' . " Time " . '</th>';
        echo '<th>' . "Status" . '</th>';
     echo "</tr>";
 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to apply this. I will let you know about it in a while.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this function:   const rowHasChanged = function(obj) {
        const lineObj = $('tr#' + obj.id);
        if !(lineObj) {
            return false;
        }

Comment: First loading: you're data represent the state of your database, so you set this data on each line (status, battery, ..). After that every 5 secs you call your endpoint to get the updated state. The `goal` of this function is to compare an object to a jquery `<th>` element, in other word compare the initial state and the updated state

Comment: yes, I want the same things, for instance, if the battery is less then 15%, then status (which is a message to user) will be "Change Battery", similarly, if the timestamp is not updated and remains the same, it means that hardware stoped working. Studying your code...

Comment: Don't hesitate if you have some questions, my code is just a basic example

Comment: Hi, I want some more explanation of the code. What (purpose) the second line of your code "const tableEl = $('#tags_table');", and first line in the function "const lineObj = $('tr#' + obj.id);" I don't have any id.

Comment: Like I said at the first rendering of your page you need to generate each tr like this `<tr id="material-line-YOUR-DB-ID">`, so you have to update the PHP code "echoing" the table. At the moment the variable `tableEl` isn't used, but you'll use it later I guess. `lineObj` will represent each line of your table after your modification :)