# Update the contents of table rather then complete table using ajax and PhP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am beginner in the PhP and Jquery. So, may be the solution to this question will be easy. I am successfully updating table using ajax and PhP. The issue is that table is updated by removing the all the data, and then populating new data.

I am looking for any other approach. After getting new data through PhP, compare new data with old data,...if there is some issue in hardware, then change the status..also keep the time from which the hardware stopped working. I ask question before [Put data from Postgresql database to table using Ajax and PhP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365732/put-data-from-postgresql-database-to-table-using-ajax-and-php), in which @Mcsky suggested me a solution, but I did not get his approach. So, How to update table data only?, instead of complete refresh of table, which feels like page refresh. here is my client code:  **estat_hardware.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> <?php include './../css/estat_hardware.css'; ?> </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="maindiv">
        <div id="tagsDiv"> 
                <h3>Estat Tags</h3>
                <?php                                      
                        echo '<table id="tags_table">';
                        echo "<thead>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                                echo '<th>' . "TAG" . '</th>';
                                echo '<th>' . "BATERIA" . '</th>';
                                echo '<th>' . " VIST ÚLTIMA COP " . '</th>';
                                echo '<th>' . "ESTAT" . '</th>';
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "</thead>";
                        echo "<tbody>";
                        echo "</tbody>";
                        echo '</table>';                            
                ?>
        </div>
</div>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        UpdateHTMLTable();
        setInterval(function() {
                UpdateHTMLTable();
        }, 5000); // 5000 millisecond(5 second)

function UpdateHTMLTable(){  
     /*   $('#tags_table tbody').empty(); */
         $('#tags_table tbody').html("");
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        console.log(data[i]);
                var row = $("<tr />");
                    $("<td />").text(data[i].mac).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(data[i].battery).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td />").text(data[i].ts).appendTo(row);


                    $battery_beacon=data[i].battery;

                    if($battery_beacon<15)
                    {
                            $status="Canvi Batteria";
                    }                   
                    else{
                        $status="Correcte ";  
                    }

                    $("<td />").text($status).appendTo(row);            
                    row.appendTo('#tags_table');     
                } 
        }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "pages/estat_hardware_server.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Server code is:**

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");  
        $host = ip";
        $port ="portNumber"; 
        $user = "abc"; 
        $pass = "...."; 
        $db = "name"; 
        $con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
        or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 
        $query = "query string for database"; 
        $result = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");
        if(pg_num_rows($result))
        {
            $data=array();
            while($row=pg_fetch_array($result))
            { 
                $data[] = array(
                'mac'=>$row['mac'],
                'ts' =>$row['ts'],
                'battery'=>$row['battery']
                 );
            }         
            echo  json_encode($data);
            pg_free_result($result);
            pg_close($con);
        }                                
?>
```

Comment: @Mcsky please have a look. thank you

Comment: I would suggest you read a few tutorials on how php works. And SQL. And jQuery. So you know what possibilities there are. As an example jQuery already has an $.ajax method... And as a direct answer to you question: Add a column to your db "updated_at" with a timestamp. Keep a global timestamp in the db for when you last checked the db, and only retrieve data where updated_at > last_checked_at

Comment: _"How to update table data only?, instead of complete refresh of table, which feels like page refresh"_ ...this appears to be what your code is doing already - it just replaces the `<tr>` tags without removing the `<table>` or reloading the whole page. Is that process somehow not working? Or what else were you expecting to happen? It's not really clear what the issue is.

Comment: @ADyson, yes, this is what my code is doing. The issue is that table disappears and updated with new data. What I want is: The table should remain as it is. only the contents should update.

Comment: you are removing the table rows and re-adding them. So the rows will indeed disappear. Then they are replaced by new rows. I don't know what else you would expect? You cannot replace the _content_ of the rows really, in case you have more or fewer rows than in the previous dataset. The header row should remain however. Is that not happening? If the header row is disappearing, then maybe try `row.appendTo('#tags_table tbody');` and see if that helps.

Comment: Header row was disappearing before, but now I resolved it using  <tbody>. Yes, I am removing table rows and re-addding them. I am thinking of some logic by which I can only update the contents of rows instead of adding each time. or something like fadein which will make table refresh transition a bit pleasing to client.

Comment: using a fade would definitely give a smoother impression to the user. I think that's better than trying to update within the rows - like I said, it'll get complicated if your new data does not have the same number of rows as the old data.

Comment: I tried fade, but did not find exact location for it in the code. Regarding data, the data will always have the same number of rows as it is just updating the status of a hardware. The database is updated though another application. so I will get new data from database, replace data in table and display to user. Where the fade in will apply in the code?

Comment: I would suggest amending your code slightly so you create a separate object for the rows. Append each new row to that object. Then when you wish to update the whole table, apply the [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) operation to the final append (where you append the rows object to your tbody. You also might want a [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) when you remove the existing rows. However if you change your approach to be updating each data item inside the rows, you won't really be able to use fade easily because you are doing lots of little changes instead of one big one

Comment: Okay, I will try this approach and will update you. Thank you.